# How to convert a merged file generated by cat command into individual files in terminal?

Tags: linux, cat

I have already merged several files into one file using cat command in linux. Now, I need the individual files; please let me know how I can recover individual files from merged file?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: Really, are you sure?

Comment: It would be possible if there is some distinct element that identifies the start or end of each file, or you happen to know the sizes of each original file and the order in which they were concatenated - see `man split` and/or `man csplit`

Comment: Depends on whether you merged a can of tomato soup with a can of cream-of-broccoli, or you "merged" a carrot with a tomato. You might give an example to help specify your scenario, otherwise you will get generic answers.

Comment: @Mary If you merged many files into one, then you lost some information - new file doesn't contain any information about "merge points" of its content. The only way to recover sources is to use some recovery tool designed for specific filesystem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_recovery_software

Comment: Thanks for all comment. I merged 7 fasta sequencing files (I don't know you know fasta file) into one file.

Comment: according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format, there is a specific format for the files, so maybe you could update your question with that information? That would give the rest of us a chance to bring general toolsets to your specific problem.

Comment: If each original file contained a *single* fasta sequence, then you could try `csplit -z file '/^>/' {*}`; the result should be files `xx00` thru `xx06` containing the individual sequences